# Reduce list to a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pulling a bunch of rows out of my database, many of which share a similar ID. I want to group the ones with the same ID into a list and generate a map that maps from the ID to the list of results. I have the following code, but it seems like there must be a simpler way of doing it with `reduce` or dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {}
for row in rows:
  type_id = row['type_id']
  values = result.get(type_id, [])
  values.append(row)
  result[type_id] = values
```

Comment: How about a default dict?

Comment: Please update a sample of rows.

Comment: That's about as good as you'll get. These types of aggregation queries always require a loop. Comprehensions generally work when the output is a filtered list of all combinations of inputs. But when you need to combine several inputs to make one output, you need a loop. For what it's worth , the last three lines can be replaced with `result.setdefault(type_id, []).append(row)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is your friend.

`collections.defaultdict(list)` will automatically create new `list`s for each key when you index into the defaultdict, so all you need is:

```
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in rows:
  result[row['type_id']].append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

btw if you are asking for oneliner comprehension. Not sure about "simplier" part though  =)

```
{type_id:[row for row in rows if row["type_id"] == type_id] for type_id in set(row["type_id"] for row in rows)}
```